# Using pip runs into an error

Tags: python, django, ssl, pip

I setup an `venv` with python3 and wanna install all my needed packages with pip. On Python2.7 it works very well, but with Python3 I run into the following error:

> pip install Django==1.11.0 pip is configured with locations that
>   require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
>
> Collecting Django==1.11.0   Could not fetch URL
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/: There was a problem confirming
>   the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module
>   is not available. - skipping   Could not find a version that satisfies
>   the requirement Django==1.11.0 (from versions: ) No matching
>   distribution found for Django==1.11.0

I have seen that there is a possible solution (not verified by myselfe) to get a `pem`-file with the certificate into my system.

Now my questions:

- is it possible to deactivate this `SSL/TLS` setting?
- in case of Django, how to get and use the certificate to work with pip successful?
- is a list with all verified (by the community) certificate availablie to run this for all packages?

Also I run the following command, I run into this error:

`(venv3) pi@roboPi:~/projects/django-rpi $ pip3 install --trusted-host  https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/  django`

> pip is configured with
>   locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is
>   not available. Collecting django   Could not fetch URL
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/: There was a problem confirming
>   the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module
>   is not available. - skipping   Could not find a version that satisfies
>   the requirement django (from versions: ) No matching distribution
>   found for django

And I have no clue, what the mistake could be.

Comment: what os are you using?

Comment: Raspbian the last Version.